# Have to import maya.cmds multiple times else maya forgets it after button press

Tags: python-2.7, button, scripting, python-import, maya

as for some background, my code is most likely a complete mess, mostly since I've only had a couple of hours scripting in my life.

For class im creating a solar system with all the standard planets and also the option for the user to input their own planet. Everything worked fine up until i tried letting the user spawn the planets with a button in the UI(an ugly button for now but a button nonetheless). If the user presses a button, say 'Sun', then the sun spawns, but only once, if he then decides to spawn sun again or any other planet for that matter, it gives an error stating that the module doesn't contain 'polycube or polysphere'. So basically, the button works once, then doesn't work anymore. If i call them from anywhere but the button, it works perfectly and indefinitely. I figured since he doesn't know polycube or polysphere, its almost as if i didn't import maya.cmds, so lets try recalling it. and low and behold that works.

So basically my question is as follows, does maya forget its imported libraries when you press a button? and How do i solve this without having to re-import maya.cmds in every function?

```
import maya.cmds as maya

class create_body:

    def __init__(self, distance, radius, bonus_scale, r, g, b):
        import maya.cmds as maya

        self.radius  = radius * bonus_scale / 1000
        self.bonusScale = bonus_scale
        self.distanceScene = distance
        self.distanceMeter = distance*1000000000

        maya.polyCube()

        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

    def color_body_custom(self):
        import maya.cmds as maya

        value = maya.colorEditor()

        self.color = [float(i) for i in value.split()]
        self.r = self.color[0]
        self.g = self.color[1]
        self.b = self.color[2]

    def spawn_body(self):
        import maya.cmds as maya

        maya.polySphere(r = self.radius)
        maya.move(self.distanceScene, moveZ = True)
        maya.move(0, 0, 0, ".scalePivot", ".rotatePivot", absolute=True)
        maya.polyColorPerVertex(rgb=(self.r,self.g,self.b), colorDisplayOption=True)

    def animate_body(self):
        import maya.cmds as maya

        orbitTimeYears = self.get_orbital_time()*10
        key = str(orbitTimeYears) + 'sec'
        maya.setKeyframe(v=0, at='rotateY', t=['0sec'], itt = 'spline', ott = 'spline')
        maya.setKeyframe(v=-360, at='rotateY', t=[key], itt = 'spline', ott = 'spline')
        maya.selectKey(attribute='rotateY')
        maya.setInfinity(pri='linear', poi='linear')

    def get_orbital_time(self):
        import math

        orbitMeter = self.distanceMeter * 2 * math.pi
        gravConst = 132690600000000000000 / self.distanceMeter
        orbitSpeed = math.sqrt(gravConst)
        orbitTimeSec = orbitMeter / orbitSpeed
        orbitTimeYears = orbitTimeSec / 31556926

        return orbitTimeYears

class create_ui:
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        self.myPlanetarySystem = window_name

        # Make sure there's only one window open by deleting the window if it exists
        self.delete_ui()

        # Create the UI
        self.myp = maya.window(self.myPlanetarySystem)
        maya.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=3, columnWidth=[(1, 150), (2, 75), (3, 75)], columnOffset=[(1, 'left', 5)])
        maya.showWindow()
        maya.window(self.myPlanetarySystem, e=True, title='TileGenerator', w=200, h=190)

        maya.button(label = 'Sun', command = partial(self.body, 0, 695.510, 10, True, 1, 1, 0))
        maya.button(label='Mercury', command = partial(self.body, 57.9, 2.439, 1000, False, 0.2, 0.2, 0))

        #Sun = create_body(0, 695.510, 10, 1, 1, 0)
        #Sun.spawn_body()

        #Mercury = create_body(57.9, 2.439, 1000, 0.2, 0.2, 0)
        #Mercury.spawn_body()
        #Mercury.animate_body()

        #Venus = create_body(108.2, 6.051, 1000, .5, 0.2, 0)
        #Venus.spawn_body()
        #Venus.animate_body()

        #Earth = create_body(149.6, 6.971, 1000, 0, 0, 1)
        #Earth.spawn_body()
        #Earth.animate_body()

        #Mars = create_body(227.9, 3.389, 1000, 0.6, 0.1, 0)
        #Mars.spawn_body()
        #Mars.animate_body()

        #Jupiter = create_body(778.5, 69.911, 100, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5)
        #Jupiter.spawn_body()
        #Jupiter.animate_body()

        #Saturn = create_body(1433.4, 58.232, 100, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7)
        #Saturn.spawn_body()
        #Saturn.animate_body()

        #Uranus = create_body(2876.6, 25.362, 100, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0)
        #Uranus.spawn_body()
        #Uranus.animate_body()

        #Neptune = create_body(4503.4, 24.622, 100, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7)
        #Neptune.spawn_body()
        #Neptune.animate_body()

    def delete_ui(self):
        if maya.window(self.myPlanetarySystem, exists=True):
            maya.deleteUI(self.myPlanetarySystem, window=True)

    def body(self, distance, radius, bonus_scale, is_sun, r = 0.5, g = 0.5, b = 0.5, *args):
        obj =  create_body(distance, radius, bonus_scale, r, g, b)
        obj.spawn_body()
        if not is_sun:
            obj.animate_body()

create_ui('myPlanetarySystem')
```

Comment: Running straight from the script editor this is working fine, though you forgot to import your partial module: `from functools import partial`

Comment: Ahh yes but not actually, I mean I just forgot to place it here, indeed my code here works but if you delete the instances of the import function after the first one the code no longer works

Comment: Even after deleting all `import` calls except the top line still works fine. Pressing a button won't magically "erase" imports, as that would be massively broken and honestly make no sense! But yes, good call on switching it to `cmds`, using it as `maya` is an odd choice espcially since you can actually run `import maya`.

Comment: I run from pycharm and that was indeed the issue, I've had no further problems

Answer (score 0):

Answer: apparently importing my maya.cmds in the shorter version: maya conflicted with the program, i should've seen this coming. In other words, there's no more issues if I just import maya.cmds as cmds.